# Using superconducting coils as a transformer

Tags: electric-current, voltage, superconductivity, plasma-physics, electromagnetic-induction

In experiments such as tokamaks, typically an ohmic transformer (primary) is used to produce current in the plasma (secondary) by swinging from to the most positive to negative magnetic field. Ideally one wants a current to always be present, although the direction isn't necessarily important. But could a superconducting coil be similarly used as the primary winding of a transformer for tokamak plasmas?

It appears one can flip the coil physically to reverse the direction of the magnetic field to produce the required flux change in time (and then continue repeating this process). Thus the direction of plasma current would change each time the superconducting coil is physically flipped, which would require work from the operator, but would essentially permit continuous operation. The primary problems I can foresee are that:

1) There will be a short moment where plasma current goes to 0 and thus rotational transform will be absent, although transport losses during this period may be negligible if operated quickly enough.

2) During the rotation of the superconducting coil, the magnetic field is no longer pointing purely vertically but may point towards the vessel with finite magnetic permeability, thus it will perturb the plasma (possibly causing great losses/instability depending on the speed of the flip).

Are there any other glaring problems? Is this something that could possibly work and/or has been tested?

Answer (score 0):

In a tokamak, the *inductive plasma current* is indeed driven by the transformer principle, where the toroidally shaped plasma corresponds to the secondary winding. Such a current drive is only possible as long as a voltage in the primary winding is ramped up or down. The magnetic field generated by that current is in the *poloidal* direction. The much stronger (roughly an order of magnitude larger) toroidal magnetic field components are generated by corresponding magnetic field coils.

You are suggesting, if I understood you correctly, to use superconducting coils instead of the plasma current. This is something which has been done and is still investigated in so-called *Levitrons* or *Spheratrons* (you might also be interested in the *heliac*). I can, however, not imagine how you would flip that coil physically during the discharge, that seems not to be possible - also note that the much stronger toroidal magnetic field might impose a problem here.

Also note that for reactor-like tokamaks, a pulsed operation is no option, they cannot rely on the inductive plasma current. For that reason, a lot of research has been put into alternative forms of current drive and, luckily, there is the so-called *bootstrap current* which is foreseen to replace the inductively driven current - this has been demonstrated in a few large-scale tokamaks to work and ITER will show that it also works on closer-to-reactor-scale levels.

Comment: Yes, bootstrap current and lower hybrid are great. I am suggesting to use superconducting coils to generate the plasma current. Essentially it would act as the ohmic transformer. But instead of swinging the magnetic field by changing current, you swing the superconducting coil itself which is at constant current. Either option produces a change in flux, and as long as the diameter of the coil can fit in the central area, this should work. My only concern is that there will be a magnetic field component in the radial direction during the transient flip, but I think that can be overcome.

Comment: Note: this would be an air core transformer as used on many tokamaks as well.